# Make input size of Keras model fixed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a pre-trained Keras model whose input size I would like to change from (None, 48000) to (1, 48000). I noticed the model has a `input_shape` attribute which, however, can't be set directly:

```py
>> model = tf.keras.models.load_model(path_to_model)
>> model.input_shape
(None, 48000)
>> model.input_shape = (1, 48000)
AttributeError: Can't set the attribute "input_shape", likely because it conflicts with an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a different name.
```

How do I change the input size of this model to essentially make it fixed? Note that the first layer of the model is part of a pre-trained model found on Tensorflow Hub and loaded using [`hub.KerasLayer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/api_docs/python/hub/KerasLayer).

In case it helps, here's the model summary:

```py
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 keras_layer_1 (KerasLayer)  (None, None, 12288)       24524288  
                                                                 
 lambda_1 (Lambda)           (None, 12288)             0         
                                                                 
 dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, 12288)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 49156     
                                                                 
 softmax_1 (Softmax)         (None, 4)                 0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 24,573,444
Trainable params: 24,573,444
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: In `(None, 48000)` None implies the batch size which can vary. You can pass a tensor of `(1,48000)` to it.

Comment: Yup, I know that, but I want the input size to be *fixed* rather than variable